# Visual Studio C++ - unresolved symbol __environ

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-construction

I'm using VS 2008 and compile my application with Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).
At link time I receive the following error:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __environ
```

Where the symbol is defined?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are using /Md (or variants), the symbols `_environ` and `_wenviron` are replaced by function calls. You need to track down the code that uses these (obsolete and deprecated) symbols, and make them [use the proper function names](http://collagefactory.blogspot.com/2009/06/unresolved-external-symbol-environ.html). I found lots of people with the same problem as you in [google](http://www.google.co.nz/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enNZ314NZ314&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=unresolved+external+symbol+__environ) also.

I found some more detail [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stxk41x1(VS.80).aspx):

> Polling _environ in a Unicode context
>   is meaningless when /MD or /MDd
>   linkage is used. For the CRT DLL, the
>   type (wide or multibyte) of the
>   program is unknown. Only the multibyte
>   type is created because that is the
>   most likely scenario.

If you change the use of the symbol `_environ` to the wide character version `_wenviron`, your original code will probably work.

Comment: Ok, so I need to use getenv_s, _wgetenv_s and _putenv_s, _wputenv_s. But what if I want iterate over all environment variables?

Comment: I added a bit more detail, it looks like you should use the _wenviron symbol if you are using /Md

Answer (score 1):

As the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stxk41x1%28VS.80%29.aspx) describes, _environ is declared in Stdlib.h and implemented in the crt lib.

Therefore you might have a problem with linking with this library, or maybe it's picking up the wrong lib (try checking your build paths).