# how can I fix the MSVC 2005 error: unresolved external symbol __environ

Tags: c++, c, environment-variables, visual-c++

In my application, I need direct access to the _environ variable because I must have something like the glibc unsetenv (you cannot have that with setenv or putenv).

This is the code I need to use:

```
//////////////////////
// unsetenv for WIN32, taken from libc source
int unsetenv(const char *name)
{
  size_t len;
  char **ep;

  if (name == NULL || *name == '\0' || strchr (name, '=') != NULL)
    {
      return -1;
    }

  len = strlen (name);

  ep = _environ;
  while (*ep != NULL)
    if (!strncmp (*ep, name, len) && (*ep)[len] == '=')
      {
    /* Found it.  Remove this pointer by moving later ones back.  */
    char **dp = ep;

    do
      dp[0] = dp[1];
    while (*dp++);
    /* Continue the loop in case NAME appears again.  */
      }
    else
      ++ep;

  return 0;
}
```

It has worked fine until we got some problems with manifests on some systems, so we tried to use the static version of the runtime library (/MT flag).

Now, I am getting this error:

```
unresolved external symbol __environ
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170427/visual-studio-c-unresolved-symbol-environ) and at many other places that this variable has become obsolete and deprecated. I wonder about the possible solution. I also cannot use the _wenviron variable because we want to support Windows 98.

In the project settings, I explicitely set it to use MBCS (i.e., not Unicode). I am a bit stumbled here. Is there anything else I must set?

Just for testing, I also tried the Unicode version. I.e. this code:

```
int unsetenv(const wchar_t *name)
{
  size_t len;
  wchar_t **ep;

  if (name == NULL || *name == '\0' || wcschr (name, '=') != NULL)
    {
      return -1;
    }

  len = wcslen (name);

  ep = _wenviron;
  while (*ep != NULL)
    if (!wcsncmp (*ep, name, len) && (*ep)[len] == '=')
      {
    /* Found it.  Remove this pointer by moving later ones back.  */
    wchar_t **dp = ep;

    do
      dp[0] = dp[1];
    while (*dp++);
    /* Continue the loop in case NAME appears again.  */
      }
    else
      ++ep;

  return 0;
}
```

I wonder a bit why that even compiled because I explicitly have set it to use MBCS and not Unicode. But maybe that means something else. (Can somebody enlighten me here?)

Anyway, this results in these errors:

```
1>AuxLib.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __wenviron
1>ExtractInfo.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __environ
```

AuxLib.obj is the file with this unsetenv(). So one error more than before.

Comment: I am reading between the lines here, but it sounds like: you have done some experiments and you ARE able to link to the _wenviron variable using the same compile and link flags, but not _environ?

Comment: I just tried that: I recoded it to use _wenviron (which was not really a solution for me, but just for testing), but then I got the error: unresolved external symbol __wenviron

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand, what's wrong with [getenv_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tb2sfw2z(VS.80).aspx)()?  It is the function equivalent of the global variable __environ.  It is multibyte, not unicode, so it should work fine on all platforms targetted by the VS 2005 compiler.  the "_s" means "safe", meaning the operation was re-designed to reduce exploitability by hackers via buffer overflows, etc.

Comment: I must that code above to work. That code will overwrite the memory where _environ is pointing to. There is no MSVC function I know about which can do that.

Comment: The OP is trying to delete an environment variable from the globally-shared libc variable.  I don't know of a library function that performs that operation for the OP, and it would be nice as it could do so in a thread-safe manner.

Comment: Sorry, I see that now.  From what I've seen, the only reliable way to delete an environment variable is to use the Win32 function SetEnvironmentVariable and pass a NULL for the value.  This API is only supported on Windows 2000 and above.

Comment: And what can I do if I want to have it working on Win98 and above?

Comment: According to the VS 2008 documentation, the requirements for SetEnvironmentVariable are:
Client: Requires Windows Vista, Windows XP, Windows 2000 Professional, Windows NT Workstation, Windows Me, Windows 98, or Windows 95.

MSDN probably is reflecting discontinued support for Windows 98.

Comment: Ah thanks for the information. That would then solve at least this code part. But it seems I got some more similar problems in other files (where I don't even have the source code, only a binary lib-file).